Entity Framework error: "entity can not be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'}"
I am trying to use EF and have this code:
public class Test : BackgroundService
{
    WordsContext _db;

    public Test(WordsContext db) 
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) 
    {
        var uw = await getUserWord();
        uw.Status = 2;
        await Save(uw);
        uw = await getUserWord();
        uw.Status = 3;
        await Save(uw);
        return;
    }

    private Task<UserWord> getUserWord() 
    {
        return _db.UserWords.Where(uw => uw.UserId == 111).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    private Task<int> Save(UserWord uw) 
    {
        _db.UserWords.Update(uw);
        return _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}

When I run this code, I get an error:

The instance of entity type 'UserWord' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked

If I use Find instead of Where, all works well, but I have a complex query and I need to use Where.
Could someone help me with this problem? How can I deal with this situation?
The code is hypothetical, just to show my problem. I can change only the code inside the functions. It is important to make some similar queries in the same function

Set EntityEntry.State property to Detached?

I'm afraid the simplification also removes the issue. This code should run fine. That said, you should remove _db.UserWords.Update(uw). The change tracker takes care of doing the right updates.

The problem was in the repeated requests and the external "repository" class (in this particular example, the Save function). When I moved to the DB factory, the problem disappeared (I used a new context in every repeated query).
